# convert json to csv and store it in a variable in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I am using csv module to convert json to csv and store it in a file or print it to stdout.

```
def write_csv(data:list, header:list, path:str=None):
    # data is json format data as list
    output_file = open(path, 'w') if path else sys.stdout
    out = csv.writer(output_file)
    out.writerow(header)
    for row in data:
        out.writerow([row[attr] for attr in header])
    if path: output_file.close()
```

I want to store the converted csv to a variable instead of sending it to a file or stdout.

say I want to create a function like this:

```
def json_to_csv(data:list, header:list):
    # convert json data into csv string
    return string_csv
```

NOTE: format of data is simple

data is list of dictionaries of string to string maping

```
[
    {
        "username":"srbcheema",
        "name":"Sarbjit Singh"
    },
    {
        "username":"testing",
        "name":"Test, user"
    }
]
```

I want csv output to look like:

```
username,name
srbcheema,Sarbjit Singh
testing,"Test, user"
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting JSON to CSV is not a trivial operation. There is also no standardized way to translate between them...

For example

```
my_json = {
   "one": 1,
   "two": 2,
   "three": {
      "nested": "structure"
   }
}
```

Could be represented in a number of ways...

These are all (to my knowledge) valid CSVs that contain all the information from the JSON structure.

```
data
'{"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": {"nested": "structure"}}'
```

```
one,two,three
1,2,'{"nested": "structure"}'
```

```
one,two,three__nested
1,2,structure
```

In essence, you will have to figure out the best translation between the two based on your knowledge of the data. There is no right answer on how to go about this.

Comment: I have updated the data format, it is simple list of string maps in my requirement

Comment: OK, and how would you want it represented as a CSV?

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively knew to Python so there's probably a better way, but this works:

```
def get_safe_string(string):
    return '"'+string+'"' if "," in string else string

def json_to_csv(data):
    csv_keys = data[0].keys()
    header = ",".join(csv_keys)
    res = list(",".join(get_safe_string(row.get(k)) for k in csv_keys) for row in data)
    res.insert(0,header)
    return "\n".join(r for r in res)
```